# Pulling remote file with stream or batch job in Spring-XD?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-xd, spring-batch-admin

Need to pull the content from a remote file, do some optional processing, and save in a data repository. As far as the protocol for file transferring, SFTP, HTTP and FTP are the options.

Since SFTP is available as source module in Spring-XD, is it doable to use it to pull file content as the source in a stream? Since SFTP is also available in Spring Batch, which solution will be more sensible? Using Spring-XD SFTP or Spring-Batch SFTP to pull data from remote file? What is the difference between them in essence?

Some of other concerns will include parallel transfer to achieve high transfer throughput and fault tolerant (resuming from interrupted transferring).

Thanks,
t.s.tao

Comment: Please share the source, If anyone has developed custom job to download a file from SFTP using Spring XD